# JSX dynamic tag with properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `systemStatus` folder of components. They are exposed with an `index.js` file like this:

```
export UserCount from './UserCount'
```

I have a JSX component named `Status` that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as SystemStatus from './systemStatus'

export default ({
    name,
    state,
    component
}) => {
    const CustomTag = `SystemStatus.${component}`;
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <SystemStatus.UserCount {...{name, state}} />
            {/*<CustomTag {...{name, state}}/>*/}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Its job is to load rows of named components.

I then have a component named `UserCount` that looks like this:

import React from 'react'

```
export default ({
    name,
    state
}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="col-md-3">{name || 'Name is missing.'}</div>
            <div className="col-md-3">
                {state ? state.count : 0}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Loading the `UserCount` component via `<SystemStatus.UserCount {...{name, state}} />` works just fine. However, if I try using the `CustomTag` I get this error:

> Unknown prop `state` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element.

How can I pass along these properties leveraging a variable? Do I need to export them differently?

Comment: Have you imported `CustomTag` from somewhere?

Comment: `CustomTag` is  string? I thought it must be a Component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just assigning `CustomTag` incorrectly.  You are just setting it to a string when you want to set it to the actual component function.

Try this:

`const CustomTag = SystemStatus[component];`

Comment: Absolutely the right answer; thanks so much! I can accept it in about 9 minutes.